# Mono For Android, FindViewById A CheckBoxPreference?

Tags: c#, android, mono, preference

I have a PreferenceScreen, where the user can check/uncheck a checkbox.

To get access any Control in the Activity I used always:

```
var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
```

Well now, I want to access my `CheckBoxPreference`..
, but its not working and I get this Exception:

*The type 'Android.Preferences.CheckBoxPreference' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Android.App.Activity.FindViewById(int)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Android.Preferences.CheckBoxPreference' to 'Android.Views.View'.*

How my PreferenceScreen.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Basic"
    android:id="@+id/preferenceCategory">
    <CheckBoxPreference
      android:id="@+id/preferenceCheckBox"
      android:key="usetestdata"
      android:title="Testdata ON/OFF"
      android:defaultValue="true" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and the not working code:

```
var aCheckBox = FindViewById<CheckBoxPreference>(Resource.Id.preferenceCheckBox);
aCheckBox.Enabled = false;
```

Maybe someone can help me and tell me on how to access controls within an activity from a PreferenceScreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for using PreferenceActivity

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //add the prefernces.xml layout
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    final CheckBoxPreference cf = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("checkbox"));
    cf.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                         // do something here
                         return false;
        }
    });
}
```

your preferences.xml in xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="checkbox"
        android:title="Title"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, I could access my CheckBoxPreference.. Do you also know, how I could now set CheckBoxPreference to IsEnabled = false? There's no Property Enabled, like the normal CheckBox has.. any ideas?

Comment: using this method you can set value cf.setValue(true);

Comment: I don't meant Checked/Unchecked.. I fixed the problem now anyway, I meant this: cf.Enabled = false;